# Как получить доступ к функции после компиляции webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Собираю все JS файлы в webpack.

```js
function DetailClass() {
  this.add = function() {
    //something...
    }
}

var Detail = new DetailClass();
```

После сборки в 1 файл пытаюсь запустить функцию через HTML:

```html
<div onclick="Detail.add();">Добавить</div>
```

Но ничего не срабатывает. Пишет Detail is not defined.

Comment: как вы подгружаете js покажите код

Comment: `<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/all.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Так как использую Laravel. Дело не в подключении файла, а в том, что после компиляции, webpack оборачивает функции в eval() и меняется область видимости, соответственно, я не могу получить доступ глобально. Пытался решить проблему с помощью объявления названия библиотеки в weback.config.js, но не помогло.

Comment: а если написать в консоле Detail.add()

Comment: @L.Vadim, то выдаст ошибку ясное дело потому что глобальной переменной Detail нету. Проблема ясна в общем то с ней сталкивался каждый кто пытался перевести легаси код на вебпак, сейчас опишу решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Внимание,** ответ актуален для webpack 1 а не для вышедшего в релиз пару недель назад webpack 2. Там вероятно остаются те же принципы, но несколько отличается API.

Через свой html вы обращаетесь к `Detail` как к глобальной переменной.

Она у вас глобальной и была видимо потому что `var Detail = new DetailClass();` выполнялось на уровне всего документа.

Вебпак же ожидает, что модули которые вы ему подсовываете - реальные модули, без побочных эффектов. Поэтому совершенно спокойно оборачивает все в замыкание и переменная `Detail` больше не глобальная и больше не видна из глобального контекста в котором работает инлайн обработчик.

Что делать?
**1. Простой грязный способ.**
Была переменная глобальной, глобальной ее и оставим.

```
window.Detail = new DetailClass();
```

Ну и разумеется этот код нужно выполнить раньше выполнить, чем позвать Detail из html.
В вашем коде вероятнее всего пойдет и так, потому что сомневаюсь что структура приложения у вас хорошо организована.

**2. Правильный способ.**
Внимательно прочитать [**раздел документации**](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules), который касается работы с легаси кодом который не модулен, и выбрать способ подходящий именно вам (imports-loader/exports-loader/ProvidePlugin)

Но если у вас прямо такой кусок html разметки с инлайновым обработчиком, и он не создается никаким шаблонизатором/js кодом, то вам эти способы из коробки врядли подойдут, потому что они предназначены для случаев когда клиентская часть организована нормально =)

Comment: Дело не столько в наличии или отсутствии побочных эффектов, сколько в самом понятии "модуль". Все переменные модуля - локальные по построению.